# How to add .jpg to end of string if it doesn't exist

Tags: php, string, if-statement, str-replace

I have the "original list" and I'm trying to convert it to the "desired list" using php. When the .jpg is present at the end of the string, I want to do nothing. If .jpg isn't the end of the string, I want to add .jpg to the end. The "original list" of stored in $badPhotos as one long string.

```
   Original List                                      Desired List
http://i.imgur.com/4ReyOhl                    http://i.imgur.com/4ReyOh1.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/4ReyOh2.jpg                http://i.imgur.com/4ReyOh2.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/4ReyOh3                    http://i.imgur.com/4ReyOh3.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/4ReyOh4                    http://i.imgur.com/4ReyOh4.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/4ReyOh5.jpg                http://i.imgur.com/4ReyOh5.jpg
```

I've been using the following to modify a strings if someone added a , where a . belongs, but now I need to modify the sting only if the string doesn't end in .jpg.

```
$badPhotos = str_replace(',', '.', $badPhotos);
```

Ideas? 
Thanks!

Comment: You should take a look at strpos function which give you position of a string in another string : http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php il return false, your string is not present

Comment: Loop through each line, pull the right-most 4 characters and test whether they are already ".jpg".  If not, add them

Comment: with `if (substr($badPhotos, -3)!='jpg')`

Comment: You should also consider that `.jpeg` is a valid extension for JPG files. I'm not sure if imgur makes use of them though.

Comment: For clarifications sake, are we to understand that `$badPhotos` is an array containing the string urls? You're using `$badPhotos` as if it's a string but the pluralization of the name implies otherwise...

Comment: Yes, $badPhotos is an array of string urls. Sorry, I should have mentioned that.

Comment: Topically related: [Add substring at beginning of string if doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56690217/2943403)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

More appropriate for file names, just get the name without the extension and then add it:

```
$badPhotos = pathinfo($badPhotos, PATHINFO_FILENAME) . '.jpg';
```

Or like this:

```
$badPhotos = basename($badPhotos, '.jpg') . '.jpg';
```

Just for fun, though this may mangle some filenames; remove it if it exists and then add it (DO NOT USE THIS):

```
$badPhotos = rtrim($badPhotos, '.jpg') . '.jpg';
```

For an array:

```
$badPhotos = array_map(function($v) {
                           return rtrim($v, '.jpg') . '.jpg';
                       },
                       $badPhotos);
```

Comment: I do not endorse this implementation of `rtrim()` for general use.  It is not reliable. https://3v4l.org/tiMUZ

Comment: @mickmackusa Yeah, there are two better ways that I moved to the top.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one method:

```
$str = 'http://i.imgur.com/4ReyOhl';
if (substr($str, -4, 4) != '.jpg') {
    $str .= '.jpg';
}
```

Another alternative, using [`array_walk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php):

```
$arr[] = 'http://i.imgur.com/4ReyOhl';
array_walk($arr, function (&$v) {
    $v = substr($v, -4, 4) != '.jpg' ? $v . '.jpg' : $v;
});
```

Comment: Only one detail, instead of `==` change to `===` (identical)

Comment: @rogeriolino that is completely unnecessary in this case.

Comment: I aggree, but is just a best practice.

Answer (score 2):

*"One-line"* solution using `preg_replace` function:

```
$url_list = [
    'http://i.imgur.com/4ReyOhl',
    'http://i.imgur.com/4ReyOh2.JPG',
    'http://i.imgur.com/4ReyOh3'
];

$url_list = preg_replace("/\/[^.]+(?!\.jpg)$/i", "$0.jpg", $url_list);

print_r($url_list);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://i.imgur.com/4ReyOhl.jpg
    [1] => http://i.imgur.com/4ReyOh2.JPG
    [2] => http://i.imgur.com/4ReyOh3.jpg
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[strstr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)** to determine if it's in the string already.

```
$rightPhotos = array();
foreach($badPhotos as $photo){
  if !(strstr(substr($photo,-4), ".jpg")){
    $photo .= ".jpg";
  }
  $rightPhotos[] = $photo;
}
```

Comment: The PHP manual has an explicit note to not use `strstr()` to check for the existence of a substring. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php#:~:text=If%20you%20only%20want%20to%20determine%20if%20a%20particular%20needle%20occurs%20within%20haystack%2C%20use%20the%20faster%20and%20less%20memory%20intensive%20function%20strpos()%20instead.

Answer (score 1):

### More Specific to Image Extentions,

> Checks for JPG, PNG and other image extentions by the php
> `preg_match`function

```
$string = "http://i.imgur.com/4ReyOhl";

if (preg_match('/(\.jpg|\.png|\.bmp)$/i', $String)) {
   echo "Already have an extention";
   
} else{
   echo "not image";
   $string .= ".jpg"; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the latest comment by the OP where `$badPhotos` is an array, here is an approach that you could take that would work:

```
$badPhotos = array(...);

foreach($badPhotos as $key => $value) {
    if(substr($value, -4, 4) !== '.jpg' || substr($value, -5, 5) !== '.jpeg') {
        $badPhotos[$key] = $value . ".jpg";
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** This uses a modified approach of *@MisterMartin*'s answer as applied to a loop of an array. It also uses the additional check as mentioned by *@uom-pgregorio* in his comment about jpg images that could end in `.jpeg`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$urls = array(
    'http://i.imgur.com/4ReyOhl',
    'http://i.imgur.com/4ReyOh2.jpg',
    'http://i.imgur.com/4ReyOh3',
    'http://i.imgur.com/4ReyOh4',
    'http://i.imgur.com/4ReyOh5.jpg',
);

$urls = array_map(function($value) {
    $path_info = pathinfo($value);
    if(!array_key_exists('extension', $path_info) || $path_info['extension'] != 'jpg') {
        return $value . '.jpg';
    }

    return $value;
}, $urls);

var_dump($urls);
```

I hope this could be quite reliable solution. Also, I would like to prefer any of both AbraCadaver and RomanPerekhrest answers because their solutions are really simpler. Anyway, I've tried my best to give you the solution!

Answer (score 0):

I almost like Roman's answer, but it can be reduced further.

The simple `preg_replace()` call will start at the end of the string, then lookbehind for `.jpg` and only append the file extension if it is not already at the end of the string.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/7ForR))

```
$url_list = [
    'http://i.imgur.com/4ReyOhl',
    'http://i.imgur.com/4ReyOh2.jpg',
    'http://i.imgur.com/4ReyOh3'
];

var_export(
    preg_replace("/(?<!\.jpg)$/", ".jpg", $url_list)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'http://i.imgur.com/4ReyOhl.jpg',
  1 => 'http://i.imgur.com/4ReyOh2.jpg',
  2 => 'http://i.imgur.com/4ReyOh3.jpg',
)
```